# Backpropagation 2-Dimensional Neuron Network C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network

I am learning about Two Dimensional Neuron Network so I am facing many obstacles but I believe it is worth it and I am really enjoying this learning process.

Here's my plan: To make a 2-D NN work on recognizing images of digits. Images are 5 by 3 grids and I prepared 10 images from zero to nine. For Example this would be number 7:

[image: Number Seven]

Number 7 has indexes 0,1,2,5,8,11,14 as 1s (or 3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13 as 0s doesn't matter) and so on. Therefore,  my input layer will be a 5 by 3 neuron layer and I will be feeding it zeros **OR** ones only (not in between and the indexes depends on which image I am feeding the layer).

My output layer however will be one dimensional layer of 10 neurons. Depends on which digit was recognized, a certain neuron will fire a value of one and the rest should be zeros (shouldn't fire).

I am done with implementing everything, I have a problem in computing though and I would really appreciate any help. I am getting an extremely high error rate and an extremely low (negative) output values on all output neurons and values (error and output) do not change even on the 10,000th pass.

I would love to go further and post my Backpropagation methods since I believe the problem is in it. However to break down my work I would love to hear some comments first, I want to know if my design is approachable.

- Does my plan make sense?
- All the posts are speaking about ranges ( `0->1`, `-1 ->+1`, `0.01 -> 0.5` etc ), will it work for either **`{ 0 |`** .OR. **`| 1 }`** on the output layer and not a range? if yes, how can I control that?
- I am using **`TanHyperbolic`** as my transfer function. Does it make a difference between this and **`sigmoid`**, other functions.. etc?

Any ideas/comments/guidance are appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by the description given above, I think that the design and approach taken it's correct! With respect to the choice of the activation function, remember that those functions help to get the neurons which have the largest activation number, also, their algebraic properties, such as an easy derivative, help with the definition of Backpropagation. Taking this into account, you should not worry about your choice of activation function.

The ranges that you mention above, correspond to a process of scaling of the input, it is better to have your input images in range 0 to 1. This helps to scale the error surface and help with the speed and convergence of the optimization process. Because your input set is composed of images, and each image is composed of pixels, the minimum value and and the maximum value that a pixel can attain is 0 and 255, respectively. To scale your input in this example, it is essential to divide each value by 255.

Now, with respect to the training problems, Have you tried checking if your gradient calculation routine is correct? *i.e.,* by using the cost function, and evaluating the cost function, `J`? If not, try generating a toy vector `theta` that contains all the weight matrices involved in your neural network, and evaluate the gradient at each point, by using the definition of gradient, sorry for the Matlab example, but it should be easy to port to C++:

```
perturb = zeros(size(theta));
e = 1e-4;
for p = 1:numel(theta)
    % Set perturbation vector
    perturb(p) = e;
    loss1 = J(theta - perturb);
    loss2 = J(theta + perturb);
    % Compute Numerical Gradient
    numgrad(p) = (loss2 - loss1) / (2*e);
    perturb(p) = 0;
end
```

After evaluating the function, compare the numerical gradient, with the gradient calculated by using backpropagation. If the difference between each calculation is less than 3e-9, then your implementation shall be correct.

I recommend to checkout the UFLDL tutorials offered by the Stanford Artificial Intelligence Laboratory, there you can find a lot of information related to neural networks and its paradigms, it's worth to take look at it!

http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/

Comment: Hi Andfoy and thanks. I have a weak background in Math so I need time to figure your way out. However part of your post made sense to me because my error is always 1e+02 for some reason, and my output values on all neurons are -6e+66, which I don't understand nor know why. I am stepping over each statement and monitoring trying to catch what is exactly happening

Comment: One question though. My images are Black/White images for the purpose of simplifying and learning. So even if I wanted to feed 0->255 I can't. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: How are you representing the output labels?  Which cost function is measuring the difference between your predicted values and your real outputs? No, you can input those images into the model!

Comment: Based on this tutorial: https://vimeo.com/19569529 -> Error = Sum (Target Values - Output Values) ^2. Then I divide it on the Output Layer Size -> 10 in our case, then I calculate its square root and feed it to this measurement: Average Error = (Old Average Error * SmoothingFactor + ErrorSquareRoot) / (SmoothingFactor + 1.0). Smoothing factor is 100.0 and can be adjusted. Old Average Error initial value is 1.0. So if it's a Black/White Image then it's either 0 or 255, means 0 or 1. No?